# Select currently active and immediately subsequent booking

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains bookings for borrowing assets:

```
--------
Bookings
--------

BookingID      AssetNo   Start                      End                       Status
---------      -------   -----------------------    -----------------------   ------
1              1         2023-05-31 00:00:00.000    2023-05-31 01:00:00.000   Overdue
2              1         2023-05-31 01:00:00.000    2023-05-31 02:00:00.000   Booked
3              2         2023-05-31 01:00:00.000    2023-05-31 02:00:00.000   InUse
4              2         2023-05-31 02:00:00.000    2023-05-31 03:00:00.000   Booked
5              2         2023-05-31 03:00:00.000    2023-05-31 04:00:00.000   Booked
```

For each asset, I want to select the booking that the asset is currently being borrowed against, at the current time, **and the next booking that exists for the asset after that, in time order** (if present).

For example, using the data above, when the current time is `2023-05-31 01:30:00.000`:

- `AssetNo 1` is currently being borrowed against `BookingID 1`, as the asset wasn't returned in time, and is `Overdue` against the booking (which is in the past).
- `AssetNo 2` is currently being borrowed against `BookingID 3`, as the asset is `InUse` against the booking (which is at the present time)

I want a query that will select the following from the example data set, when current time = `2023-05-31 01:30:00.000`:

```
BookingID      AssetNo   Start                      End                       Status   Active
---------      -------   -----------------------    -----------------------   ------   ------
1              1         2023-05-31 00:00:00.000    2023-05-31 01:00:00.000   Overdue  True
2              1         2023-05-31 01:00:00.000    2023-05-31 02:00:00.000   Booked   False
3              2         2023-05-31 01:00:00.000    2023-05-31 02:00:00.000   InUse    True
4              2         2023-05-31 02:00:00.000    2023-05-31 03:00:00.000   Booked   False
```

---

I can select the currently active bookings like this:

```
DECLARE @UTCNow DATETIME;
SET @UTCNow = '2023-05-31 01:30:00.000';

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        b.*
        ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY b.AssetNo ORDER BY [Start] ASC) AS time_order
    FROM Bookings b
    WHERE (b.[End] < @UTCNow AND b.Status = 'Overdue') -- past booking that started but hasn't completed
    OR (b.[Start] <= @UTCNow AND b.[End] > @UTCNow) -- booking that occurs at the present time
    ) AS b2
WHERE b2.time_order = 1
```

How can I also select the booking that *follows* the currently active booking, and for each asset, set which one is the active booking (`Active = True`), and which is a subsequent booking for the same Asset (`Active = False`)? I can use transact SQL but would prefer to use ANSI.

---

### **Update**

I've created the following SQL Fiddle that sets up the example data set. I've begun outlining a different possible approach i.e. selecting the start time of the currently active booking for each asset, and selecting the first 2 bookings for each asset from that time, ordered by `Start` `ASC`:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f51f5/7

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this:

```
DECLARE @UTCNow DATETIME;
SET @UTCNow = '2023-05-31 01:30:00.000';

WITH activeBookings AS (
  SELECT b.[AssetNo], MIN(b.[Start]) AS activeBookingStart
  FROM Bookings b
            WHERE (b.[End] <= @UTCNow AND b.[Status] = 'Overdue') -- past booking that started but hasn't completed
            OR (b.[Start] <= @UTCNow AND b.[End] > @UTCNow) -- booking that occurs at the present time
            GROUP BY b.[AssetNo]
)
SELECT 
  b2.[BookingID]
  , b2.[AssetNo]
  , b2.[Start]
  , b2.[End]
  , b2.[Status]
  , CASE
      WHEN b2.[time_order] = 1 THEN 'True'
      WHEN b2.[time_order] = 2 THEN 'False'
    END AS 'Active'
FROM (
  SELECT
    b.*
    ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY b.[AssetNo] ORDER BY [Start] ASC) AS time_order
    FROM Bookings b
    INNER JOIN activeBookings ab
    ON ab.[AssetNo] = b.[AssetNo]
    WHERE b.[Start] >= ab.[activeBookingStart]
) AS b2
WHERE b2.[time_order] IN (1,2);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f51f5/32

Answer (score 0):

Not completely clear on your expectation of the final output. Perhaps you'd like columns BookingID, AssetNo, Start, End, Status, Active, Start_Next, (and End_Next), and BookingID_Next in each output row? And I assume booking IDs are unique.

Some questions I have:

1. Why was RANK() used for the task of selecting the currently active bookings? The way I see it, just your WHERE clauses suffice for your purpose.
2. Have you considered using LEAD(), which looks at records that appear after the current record (offset is omitted here because it is optional, and the default is 1.)

Following (based on aforementioned assumptions) is my suggestion:

```
    DECLARE @UTCNow DATETIME;
    SET @UTCNow = '2023-05-31 01:30:00.000';

    SELECT 
    bookingid, assetno, [Start], [End], status, active, 
    LEAD ([Start]) OVER (PARTITION BY assetno ORDER BY [Start] ASC) AS start_next,
    LEAD (bookingid) OVER (PARTITION BY assetno ORDER BY [Start ASC]) AS bookingid_next
    FROM Bookings b
    WHERE (b.[End] < @UTCNow AND b.Status = 'Overdue')
    OR (b.[Start] <= @UTCNow AND b.[End] > @UTCNow)
```

You can add additional data points in SELECT, and ORDER BY at the end to further specify how you'd like the output to be arranged.

Comment: Hi @bluefootedboobies, thanks. If you re-read the question, I specified the exact output I need, which isn't what your suggestion would provide. `RANK` in the query I provided is used to rank the bookings selected for each asset by date order (as the `WHERE` clause can lead to two bookings being selected). The earliest booking for the asset is then selected (by selecting the earliest record retrieved, i.e. the record that has rank 1). This will be the currently active boooking. I did consider using LEAD, but I need the booking that follows each of the active bookings to be a separate row.